# Adding additional indentation to \input based on nesting

Tags: macros

I have a question on how to do a specific programmatic thing with LaTeX. Currently I'm writing technical documentation where a procedure can have nested sub-procedures, each of those also being able to nest. The trick is that I do not know exactly at which level a sub procedure could be, but I would like to add indent as a procedure is \input and remove the indent when I get to the end of the doc (pretty much a push/pop for indents).

The idea I had would look something like this:

```
\paragraph{Reference the following procedure:}
% TODO: Indent one level
\input{_MySubProcedure.tex}
% TODO: Remove one indent level
\paragraph{Next steps...}
```

Again the important point is that I don't know **exactly** how much to indent here, I just know I need to add some fixed amount and remove that same amount at the end of the \input.

Thank you very much in advance for any help that can be provided on this!

Comment: `\input` is intended to be more or less invisible but you can do for example `\begin{quote}\input{...}\end{quote}` or define an environment equivalent to quote with a more semantic name, nested quotes will indent by more each time (actually quote indents from both sides but easy to adapt to just indent on the left)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I hate answering my own question less than an hour after I post it, but I did find something that meets my needs. Using the changepage package gives me access to \adjustwidth, which I've wrapped into a new command:

```
% Indent the entire document by 1em..
\newcommand{\subprocedure}[1]{ \begin{adjustwidth}{1em}{0pt}\input{#1}\end{adjustwidth} }
```

Using the command above, I can now get the nesting I need by replacing every \input with \subprocedure.